How to make a variable for my xarray (for EOF analysis) have 3 dimensions?
I am trying to make an xarray for EOF analysis.
I want the dimensions to be DateTimeUTC, latitude, and longitude. I want the variable to be PM2.5
My dataset currently has these columns: PM2_5MC_x, AtmoT, AtmoRH, month, compliance_hours_daytime, lon, lat
with DateTimeUTC as the index.
how do I make an xarray for my EOF analysis with the dimensions to be DateTimeUTC, latitude, and longitude and input variable to be PM2.5? And how do I make the input variable (PM2.5) have 3 dimensions?
Thank you!
I've tried:

Convert from DataFrame to xarray
data_xr = xr.DataArray(
merged_data_final_filtered['PM2_5MC_x'].values,  # Values for PM2.5
coords={
'time': merged_data_final_filtered.index.values,  # Use the index for the 'time' coordinate
'latitude': merged_data_final_filtered['lat'].values,  # Latitude coordinate
'longitude': merged_data_final_filtered['lon'].values  # Longitude coordinate
},
dims=['time', 'latitude', 'longitude']  # Define the dimensions in the correct order
)
data_xr_clean = data_xr.fillna(data_xr.mean(dim='time')) # filter out NaN

But I get this error:
ValueError: different number of dimensions on data and dims: 1 vs 3
